# Exporting a database from Microsoft Azure

Tags: sql, azure, sql-server-2012

How can I export my SQL database from Microsoft Azure?

Comment: This was something I was trying to do but couldn't find any good instructions on where to start or how to do it, so I posted this once I got it figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a step by step process for exporting a database from Microsoft Azure to allow for reupload to another service.

1. Create a new Storage object. In the Azure control panel, click on NEW in the bottom left and then Data Services -> Storage -> Quick Create
2. Export the DB to the Storage object. In the Azure control panel, go to SQL DATABASES, click on your DB and an option to export should appear at the bottom of the screen. This will bring up the Export Database Settings dialog. Choose "Create a new Container" in the dialog. The new container will be put in the storage account you just created.
3. Get Account Key from Azure. Back in Azure, go to Storage -> The Storage object you created. At the bottom of the screen should be an option for Manage Access Keys.
4. Import bacpac file to SQL Server Management Studio. In the SMS Object Explorer, go to connect -> Azure Storage... and the dialog for Connect to Windows Azure Storage will come up. Go back to Azure and get the STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME and PRIMARY ACCESS KEY. Your connected storage account should now appear in the Object Explorer with yourDB.bacpac file.
5. Import Date-tier Application. Click on the yourDB.bacpac file to start and select the Import Date-tier Application option. Go though the steps, connecting to the local sever you want to store the DB in. Once finished, your full database should be available in Server Management Studio.

Further documentation: [Import a BACPAC File to Create a New User Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710052.aspx)